# How can update props in child component functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a **parent** component and a **child** component.

- The parent component sends data to the child.
- The child modifies the value and the parent should see the change reflected.

But nevertheless there is something that I am not doing well because I do not understand the mechanisms of react well.

**Parent component**

```
function ParentComponent() {
  var userName = "Didi";
  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <label>Parent - {userName}</label>
      <ChildComponent userName={userName} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child component**

```
function ChildComponent({ userName }) {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    userName = e.target.value;
  };
  return (
    <div className="ChildComponent">
      <input type="text" defaultValue={userName} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      <label>ChildComponent - {userName}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: Just as you pass `userName` as a prop to the child-component, please also try sending a callback function as a prop. Now, the `handleChange` in the child will use the callback which will be able to update the value in the parent. And, you may want to declare userName like so: `const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState("Didi");`

Comment: Read the basic tutorial of React, if you read it it will mention that props are immutable and what you need to do to mutate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React can't monitor free variables for changes. You need to store data in a state (or use some external system like Redux).

If you want to change the state from a different component, then you need to pass the function which changes it to the component.

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState("Didi");
  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <label>Parent - {userName}</label>
      <ChildComponent userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ChildComponent({ userName, setUserName }) {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
     setUserName(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="ChildComponent">
      <input type="text" defaultValue={userName} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      <label>ChildComponent - {userName}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between useState or setState to use in this case?

Comment: @Cazs — `setState` is a method found on Class Components. `useState` is a hook for Function Components. They work in significantly different ways to acheive the same result.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

**Parent component**

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  
  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <label>Parent - {username}</label>
      <ChildComponent
        username={username}
        changeUsername={value => setUsername(value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child component**

```
function ChildComponent({ username, changeUsername }) {
  const handleChange = e => {
    changeUsername(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="ChildComponent">
      <input type="text" value={username} onChange={handleChange} />
      <br />
      <label>ChildComponent - {username}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to do this:

**Parent component**

```
import {useState} from 'react';

function ParentComponent() {
  const [userName,setUserName]=useState("Didi");
  return (
    <div className="Parent">
      <label>Parent - {userName}</label>
      <ChildComponent userName={userName} setUserName={setUserName}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child component**

```
function ChildComponent({ userName,setUserName }) {
  
  return (
    <div className="ChildComponent">
      <input type="text" defaultValue={userName} onChange={(e)=>setUserName(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <label>ChildComponent - {userName}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```